# Android Binding and KitKat (API 19) issues

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat

My project includes an Android binding project which works perfectly on all devices and emulators except for KitKat (API 19) Xamarin Android Player/Genymotion emulators.

Here is the error:

```
[FAIL] Sample4JpgWithWhitelist : Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError' was thrown.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetMethodID (IntPtr kls, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Com.Googlecode.Tesseract.Android.TessBaseAPI..ctor (IProgressNotifier p0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Tesseract.Droid.TesseractApi..ctor (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Tesseract.Droid.Test.TesseractApiRecogniseTest.Setup () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
--TearDown
at Tesseract.Droid.Test.TesseractApiRecogniseTest.Tear () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What can be a problem?

Thank you!

Comment: My assumption is it is using something not found on API 19. What type of devices are you testing it on? Also which library are you binding? Looks like there was an issue in 4.4: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/issues/106

Comment: @JamesMontemagno thank you so much! I was looking for an issue on teas-two but somehow missed that one.